# Unity - Uploading and downloading files in a game using a GUI

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible in Unity to upload and download files while in a game? I want to make a minecraft-style building game and allow the user to import and use their own models (.obj files, etc), while in the game. I've been using Playfab for a backend and Photon for online cabilities, but as far as I can tell it will only work with image files (in Playfab). Is there a way to accomplish this and what would I need to use?

Comment: WebRequest can do both. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way to go is to use **Asset Bundles**

Asset Bundles are platform specific assets that you create in Unity, but that you don't put in your build. Instead you can download them later, just as you want.

The process is a bit long, but not that difficult. The unity manual is actually really good and it should be easy to follow. Here is the link:

[Asset Bundles documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html)